# How to determine which Stack Exchange site to ask cross discipline questions on

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and it got put on hold. The question is about the correct way to express a guessing function for a modified interpolation search. It's basically an interpolation search where the next guess is not weighted based on a linear distribution.

The individual who put the question on hold said it belongs on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) or Stack Overflow. Well, which one?! It is definitely a math problem, because it asks about derivatives and other methods for deriving the correct function. But it also asks about interpolation search which is a computer science topic and a programming topic. How do I determine which site to put it on? Sometimes I feel like there are too many Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: May be useful in your quest: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: There's a stack exchange meta? This is getting really annoying. These sites spread like weeds.

Comment: There's always been a meta Stack Exchange.  But used to be called MSO until about 2 years ago.

Comment: First question to ask - why did you put it on Code Review initially?  Is it because you have code you were asking about or are you talking theoretical/design type question?

Comment: Well I assume the average coder knows something about search algorithms. And the interpolation search is a well known search that is documented in pretty much every language out there. So asking someone to change one line of the code seemed like review, since interpolation search already...works....even for the question I was asking. I considered code golf but the question didn't seem entertaining enough. Quite honestly, I have no idea where to put it and I'm afraid to ask it anywhere now because I'm quite sure I'll be reprimanded and shown the door again. This happens to me all the time btw.

Comment: Also, I don't know enough about the answer to know where it belongs. I don't know if I can't solve it because of a weakness in my math skills or if I just don't know some algorithmic method. But I do know that the math of the problem and the fact that its part of the interpolation search make it legitimate to both.

Comment: What do you want out of this meta question - figure out where to post your specific question?  Or figure out how to pick the right site for your questions in general?  If you want help with your specific question, quoting the question itself might be helpful.

Comment: I'm with @psubsee2003 on this one; I'd like to see the question too.  It's tough to make an accurate judgment call just from hearing your description, but at least from what I get of what you're asking, Code Review definitely wasn't the right place.  That site in particular focuses on working, functional, real code but could do with another person taking a look at it to see if there are improvements that could be made as opposed to one trying to figure out how to solve a problem.

Comment: I would settle for knowing where to ask it. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134658/interpolation-search-on-logarithmic-distributions

Comment: I give up. I can't even ask questions about questions on the correct site.